# How to fixed mysql query escape issue with node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my API I have set some code as this.

```
 if('searchStr' in body){
        filter = filter + ` AND table.colName LIKE = '%${body.searchStr}%' `;
 }
```

This works fine when I pass string like this => **test**

But when I pass this => **`test** , My API gone a crash. How could I prevent this in node ?

I have tried to use `\` but it's not working for me.

**Tried**:

```
\'%${body.searchStr}%\'          // Not works for me.
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape string

```
filter = filter + " AND table.colName LIKE = '%"+connection.escape(body.searchStr)+"%' ";
```

Comment: sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'= \'%\'\\\'Good\'%\'

Comment: Try replace `+ SqlString.escape(body.searchStr) +` for module https://github.com/mysqljs/sqlstring

Comment: It's a another npm module.

Comment: Try it `+ mysql.escape(body.searchStr) +`